# why i can't get the right answer of python with the accuracy of float if the number is too small, for example pow(1e+15+1,1/3)

Tags: python, pow

There is my function

```
def eformat(f, prec, exp_digits):
    s = "%.*e"%(prec, f)
    mantissa, exp = s.split('e')
    return "%se%+0*d"%(mantissa, exp_digits+1, int(exp))
n=int(input().strip())
l_test=[]
for i in range(n):
    l_test.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
def fonc(l,r,k):
    res=0
    for i in range(l,r+1):
        r1=10**(-k)
        print(r1)
        res+=(i+(r1))**(1/3)-i**(1/3)
    return res
for i in range(n):
    l,r,k=l_test[i]
    res=fonc(l,r,k)`enter code here`
    print(eformat(res,5,3))
```

With input of 1 /n 1 1 15 and the correct answer should be 3.3333E+016

Comment: Try using decimal.Decimal - are the results a little better?

Comment: Much of your code does not seem relevant to your question. Can you reduce that to a **minimal** [mre]?

Comment: you should be careful adding really small numbers to really big numbers. Double precision only holds 16 decimal places. 1e15+1 returns correctly, but note that that's near the limit. 1e16+1==1e16 as far as python is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for your answers , it works after using Decimal.